# How do you win a scared/wild-ish kitten over?

Tags: cats, behavior

I have two kittens.

Friday, 4-ish months, black long-ish haired cat, bold and adaptable. Great dog-like kitten. No problem.

Douglas, 2-ish months, siamese kitten (male). He is scared, does not like to be near me, does not want to be touched/picked up. Part of it is my mistake - he kept running away from me, so I tried to grab him which he did not appreciate. He was wild/scared even before though.

How do I win the young one over?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [I adopted a 14 week old kitty](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19792/i-adopted-a-14-week-old-kitty) or perhaps [Made my cat scared of me, need help](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17015/made-my-cat-scared-of-me-need-help). Can you update your question to explain how your question is different from these?